# Git command line thinks I am a past account I previously used

Tags: git, github

My git intall seems to think I am still a previous user I had dispite the lengths I've gone through to remove this.

Currently the only feedback I am getting is this error message

```
remote: Permission to Mike4driver/LoftyPracticalDjangoProject.git denied to MikeTokensoft.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Mike4driver/LoftyPracticalDjangoProject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

MikeTokensoft was my previous account I used for work and I'm trying to switch back over to my personal account. Ive switched my work email in my global config to my personal one and verified this has changed to that and it is shown as such in new commits I make locally. My old account had a Access token I was using for it which I removed. My understanding is that that was what was located in my .git-credentials file so I removed everything in there which was just that one line. Then I removed from my git config everything under the [credentials] section.

I'm not sure where else I can look to find out where my machine is currently pulling the MikeTokensoft Identity from and how I can remove this.
Here is the output of my git config -l

```
user.email=My Real email that I replaced for stackoverflow
user.name=My Real Name that I replaced for stackoverflow
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/Mike4driver/LoftyPracticalDjangoProject.git
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check first your git credential helper:

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

If you get a value (say `xxx`), check what is stored in that helper:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-xxx get
```

If you see the old token, for the old account, remove it, and store the new one.

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=Mike4driver" | git-credential-xxx erase

printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=NewAccount\npassword=yourToken" | git-credential-xxx store
```

Comment: thanks for the help however 

git config --global credential.helper

does not seem to return anything for me

Comment: @MichaelEdwards What OS are you on? With which version of Git?

Comment: git version 2.38.1 and I am running Manjaro

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Create a dummy repository, and in it, execute `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin`: do you see your old user in those settings?